# Fatal error: execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, database, phpmyadmin

Today I tried to access phpMyAdmin but I couldn't because of the this error message:

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\vendor\samyoul\u2f-php-server\src\U2FServer.php on line 10

So...I tried to modify max_execution_time in php.ini file but it didn't work

Also, in line 10 from U2FServer.php file is the class name:

[image]

Why is this happening? Can you help me, please?

Thank you

Comment: You're code is exceeding the maximum configured execution time. Check your php.ini for `max_execution_time `

Comment: @Kisaragi I tried to modify that but it didn't work

Comment: Did you reload you conf files?

Comment: @Kisaragi reload? Do you mean reinstall xampp?

Comment: Did you enable two-factor authentication for this account? Are you seeing this error when you first try to log in? Are you able to see the form for username and password or does the error appear before even that stage? Which phpMyAdmin version are you using? How have you installed phpMyAdmin (is it part of a kit such as XAMPP/WAMP, your distribution's package manager, download directly from phpmyadmin.net, etc)?

Comment: I can acess phpMyAdmin. Problem solved. Thank  you